# how  to have custom post template including custom write panels for the users to post

Tags: custom-field, custom-write-panel

I would like to have a separate custom page where the logged in users can post their content. 
Add post title,
add content,
add check boxes,
image/file uploads,

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: wouldn't the Wordpress admin do just that?

Comment: I want it on a custom page. I want a completely customized admin page. My clients fine WordPress admin interface to be confusing and difficult, I would like to add a simple easy UI to add and edit post along with some of my custom write panels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe *scribu*'s [Front end Editor](http://scribu.net/wordpress/front-end-editor) would be an easy way to update your website if your client finds the WP admin to be "*confusing and difficult*".

But also bare in mind that the admin is [customizable](http://www.google.com/search?&q=customize%20wordpress%20admin) through [admin themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes), as well as various scripts and [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=customize%20admin). To cite only one plugin, try [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/), it will allow you to remove a lot of unnecessary stuff from the interface.